# Setting a button in every navigation item of a UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, ios4, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I know it is possible to add a custom button in a navigation item using this:

```
UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
[infoButton addTarget:self
               action:@selector(showInfo:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// Add the info button to the navigation bar
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoButton];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:barButtonItem
                                  animated:YES];
[barButtonItem release];
```

But is there a way of setting this button in every subview pushed to the navigation stack without having to replicate this code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also subclass UIViewController, then override:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
        [infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showInfo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        // Add the info button to the navigation bar
        UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoButton];
        [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:YES];

        [barButtonItem release];
    }
    return self;
}
```

then when you make a new VC, subclass this class instead of `UIViewController`

Answer (score 0):

When pushing a "next" view controller you can add this code:

```
nextVC.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem copy];
```

But you have to overwrite the selector (if you want your button to send data to your nextViewController object):

```
[nextVC.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTarget:nextVC ...];
```